# How to accomplish Android Widget with multiple ImageView each with multiple onClick Listener?

Tags: android, onclick, widget, android-pendingintent

I'm newbie to Android development. 
I'm having problem here and hope someone could help me out.

On the widget, let's say it has 3 components which are ImageViews.

- What I want is when users click on ImageViewOne, PendingIntentOne
  bring users to ClassOne.
- And when users click on ImageViewTwo,
  PendingIntentTwo bring users to ClassTwo.
- And when users click on
  ImageViewThree, PendingIntentThree bring users to ClassThree.

How to do this?
At the moment I could only have 1 PendingIntent for the whole widget.

---

Never mind, I got it already
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081818/how-to-make-several-buttons-in-widget-send-broadcast-to-the-same-widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have only 1 pendingIntent ?

```
Intent intentLogo = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
Bundle extrasLogo = new Bundle();
intentLogo.putExtras(extrasLogo);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Widget.REQUEST_CODE, intentLogo, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Widget.REQUEST_CODE, intentLogo, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Widget.REQUEST_CODE, intentLogo, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```